# How do i delete specific word only from the first line using SED

Tags: sed, sqlplus

I would like to delete the word SQL> to number 7 only.
Is there a way to do it?

Before

```
SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7  PPM056                               |2  |2018 JUN 21 11:35:39      |AROCKIADOSS ARUN GODWIN                                                               |RE$AIN          |G2994424K              |PSA
PPM592                              |2  |2018 JUN 21 12:56:14      |BALAMURUGAN MANOJ
```

After

```
PPM056                              |2  |2018 JUN 21 11:35:39      |AROCKIADOSS ARUN GODWIN                                                               |RE$AIN          |G2994424K              |PSA
    PPM592                              |2  |2018 JUN 21 12:56:14      |BALAMURUGAN MANOJ
```

Comment: you were given some advice for same question you asked yesterday.. did you try any [sed resources](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info) to find out how to do a simple search and replace? you are expected to show research effort to get help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed '1s/^SQL>.*7[[:space:]]*//' <infile >outfile
```

The `1` tells `sed` to apply the next command to the first line of `infile` only.  The command is a substitution (`s`) that will replace everything from the first `SQL>` up to and including a `7` followed by zero or more spaces or tabs.  Note that this will work on the example data only because there is only one such `7` on the first line.

The result will be saved in `outfile`.

Comment: @Sundeep Please do not discourage helping. I dislike that type of questions too, but I see no way to prevent them that doesn't lead to a big pile of unanswered questions.

Comment: I've had little bit of success when I comment and ask OP to include research effort.. it is not much, but it helps me.. please continue to contribute, I certainly don't have a definite answer for these cases :)

Comment: @Sundeep We see a lot of these on U&L as well, and asking for what they have tried very seldom gives anything, most probably because they simply do not know where to start.